# Can Spring DI deduce depenendencies from code like Autofac, without annotations?

Tags: spring, ioc-container, autofac

Autofac is an Inversion of Control container for .net. It has this attractive (to me) feature:

> When Autofac instantiates a component, it satisfies the component's
>   dependencies by finding and instantiating other components.
>
> Components express their dependencies to Autofac as constructor
>   parameters:
>
> ```
> public class TaskController : IController 
> {
>     public TaskController(ITaskRepository tasks) { ... }
> }
> ```
>
> In this case Autofac will look for another component that provides the
>   `ITaskRepository` service and call the constructor of `TaskController`
>   with that component as a parameter.

*(source: http://code.google.com/p/autofac/)*

For the simplest case where there's a single implementation for a given interface this works neatly - without requiring any meta-data about the dependency (attributes/XML/config class).

**Does Java's "Spring DI" container support the same functionality?**

Comment: The Spring IoC container can only control what's inside thus configured.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm looking for the DI container to deduce this information from the
>   bytecode rather than me having to supply it in XML.

I don't believe Spring has such functionality. If you could annotate your constructor like so

```
@Autowired
public TaskController(ITaskRepository tasks) { ... }
```

and there was only one bean that implements `ITaskRepository` in the context, then Spring could figure it out, but you'll need the annotation.

---

Correct me if I misunderstood your question.

If you don't have control of the class to add annotations, you can still use the `<bean>` `<constructor-arg>` element to reference and use another bean when invoking the constructor.

```
<bean id="taskRepository" class="com.some.TaskRepositoryImpl" />

<bean id="taskController" class="com.some.TaskController">
    <constructor-arg ref="taskRepository" />
</bean>
```

Alternatively, with Java configuration

```
@Bean
public ITaskRepository taskRepository() {
    return new TaskRepositoryImpl();
}

@Bean
public TaskController taskController() {
    return new TaskController(taskRepository());
}
```

Comment: Thanks but sorry - that's not what I'm looking for. I'm looking for the DI container to deduce this information from the bytecode rather than me having to supply it in XML.

Comment: This is all common (best) practice with the DI containers for .NET. How do other Java DI frameworks handle this?